# How to fix compilation error when trying to call a generic TypeScript method

Tags: typescript, generics

I am not sure how to title this question, so pardon if it is not descriptive. But basically the code that I have that is leading to the compilation error is similar to this:

```
class Box<T> {

}

class Gen<T extends Box<number>> {
    private action(array: Array<T>): Array<T> {
        return new Array()
    }

    private useAction() {
        let x:Box<number>[] = new Array<Box<number>>();
        // This leads to the compilation error
        this.action(x)
    } 
}
```

I would expect this to work.

I defined `action` to take an array of any type, hence the `array:Array<T>`

In `useAction` I am calling the `action` method.

I am calling it with an array of `Box<number>`

Since I defined it to take any type, I expected passing a variable of type `Box<number>` to `action` should then work.

But it fails with a compilation error:

> Argument of type 'Box[]' is not assignable to parameter of
>   type 'T[]'.   Type 'Box' is not assignable to type 'T'.
>       'Box' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint
>   'Box'.

I can't decipher the error message. Why is it failing and how do I fix it?

Comment: `T` extends `Box`, but this does not mean that you can pass an array of `Box` when an array of `T` was expected, because `T` could have additional properties that `Box` does not have. E.g. what if `Box` has a property `color`, but the object you pass as `T` has properties `color` and `size`?

You say you defined action() to take any type, but this is not what you've done - you've defined it to take an array of `T`, which may be more specific than an array of `Box`.

Comment: You can alter `action` to [have an unbound type parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=4&ssc=28&pln=4&pc=39#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCD2APAPAFQHzQN7QL4Ch9RIYBxAUwDs1pzEAXKgExgRUoFcBbAI3ICd0mLPmjQADvwCWANzCNoYYPSnxqAVVoNmrJMk68BQgBRh+-MAE8AXNACC5q8nXoAlLYcXLz4aLHR+cnoOfkpoSnIAd3tHS2NXPwI-SVl5cmgOCHI7ZVVKeOw-MRAg6ERbNn1uPkEAbQBdaABecKiYr2RKgxqTVwBuIugAeiHoVAALKRgSsBZoenh58fTgeC5xKXAVNVpzeH5B+kmIADolbfzEBLECXCA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of generics in typescript. You can have generics on classes, or on functions.

When you have a generic class (`Gen<T>`), the whole class is generic and all of its non-static methods can use the generic type parameter (`T`). But its methods are not generic, and they will be like any regular method.

That is because when you create an object from your class (`const gen = new Gen<SomeClass>();`) and call a method on it (`gen.action(something)`), the type parameter (`T`) is already fully known (`SomeClass`).

I think what you want is not to have a generic class, but to have a generic method on your class:

```js
class Box<T> {

}

class Gen {
    private action<T extends Box<number>>(array: Array<T>): Array<T> {
        return new Array()
    }

    private useAction() {
        let x:Box<number>[] = new Array<Box<number>>();
        // This leads to the compilation error
        this.action(x)
    }
}
```

This way, you will create an object of your class with no type parameters (`const gen = new Gen();`), but the `action` method can be called on an array of any type that extends `Box<number>`.

---

You can also make both your class and your method generic (which I don't think is what you want, but I will add an example for completeness):

```js
class Box<T> {

}

class Gen<T extends Box<number>> {
    private action<U extends Box<number>>(array: Array<U>): Array<U> {
        return new Array()
    }

    private useAction() {
        let x:Box<number>[] = new Array<Box<number>>();
        // This leads to the compilation error
        this.action(x)
    }
}
```

Comment: "the whole class is generic and all of its non-static methods can use the generic type parameter (T). But its methods are not generic," - is that not contradictory?

Comment: No it is not. The methods are in the context of the class, so they all have the type parameter **of the class**, but they don't have any type parameters **of themselves** (unless defined explicitly like in my last example). So they are not generic themselves, but in a generic class. (Read the paragraph following the one you mentioned, it explains.)

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!